# Распознавание речи на русском для диктовки на десктопе

Tags: windows, распознавание-речи

А что не появилось ли уже программ, которые позволяют делать диктовку по русски с голоса на настольном компьютере?

На мобильных устройствах давно уже можно делать поиск по голосовым запросам, распознавание гугла работает почти безупречно, да и у Яндекса неплохо (пользуюсь в навигаторе).

А на дескопе? Чтобы надиктовать заметки, например?

Comment: Есть [Алиса](https://alice.yandex.ru/). Правда, не знаю, сможет ли она надиктованное сохранить в файлик.

Answer (score 0):

Dragon Dictation работает стабильно и распознает более 15 языков. К счастью для всех нас русский тоже поддерживается )))

Comment: А где можно посмотреть, что Dragon Dictation поддерживаете русский?